# Extracting a specific CSS Declaration using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to extract the @font-face declaration from CSS using regex (in javascript), but I've been struggling to make it work. For example, if the code looks like this:

```
@font-face {font-family: Calibre;font-weight: 100;src:url(/next/contenthash/next/fonts/calibre/thin/calibre_thin.contenthash.89933a98c87fcc1f9eaf73b8e8dce74ba01bc153.woff) format("woff");font-display: swap}
```

I'd like my result to be this object:

```
{
    font-family: Calibre;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url(/next/contenthash/next/fonts/calibre/thin/calibre_thin.contenthash.89933a98c87fcc1f9eaf73b8e8dce74ba01bc153.woff) format("woff");
    font-display: swap
}
```

Any idea on the best way to do this sort of thing in javascript? This is relatively easy if it were a single line. But sometimes I see non-minified CSS and I'm not sure how I would capture this object if it spanned multiple lines.

Any help is appreciated — thanks!

Comment: maybe `(?<=@font-face )\{.*\}` ? You could then replace each `;` with `;\n`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work @mashuptwice. Here's the scriptular link: shorturl.at/rxNPV

Comment: Well, it works with the data you've provided as a single line. `(?<=@font-face )\{(.|\s)*\}` would work with the data in multiline

Comment: @mashuptwice Hmm that doesn't seem to work either. I'm trying to decipher this to see if I can get it to work. I understand everything except for the "<=" as the fourth and fifth character. What do those do?

Comment: I've tested it with both [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yflIyd/2) as well as your regex engine, both seem to work fine. See my answer with the explanation of the different parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I ended up coming to (with the help of the comments above)

```
let regex = /(?<=@font-face)(\s*{[\s\S]*?})/g;
let match = css.match(regex);
```

I was missing an understanding of capture groups and lookback operators.